# Small clauses (or verbless clauses)

Tags: grammaticality, ellipses

Small clauses are clauses with "to be" deleted.

> I found him (to be) difficult.

And as we all know, an adjective complement can be added afterward.

> I found him (to be) difficult *to work with*.
>
> I found him happy *to do the job*.
>
> She appeared unable *to work with me*.
>
> I considered him incapable *of doing anything*.

And there was this sentence:

> **a.** I thought him *angry at me*.

Somehow, this sentence sounded extremely unnatural to me. Also this.

> **b.** She called me different *from others*.
>
> **c.** I called him incapable *of doing anything*.

Even though they are theoretically correct, since there is an adjective complement after the adjective in the small clause, they sound extremely strange with the adjective complement. Are those sentences grammatically wrong? Do they sound natural to you? I am not a native speaker, so it's rather hard for me to judge.

Also, is it true that an adjective complement can be used if there is an adjective in the sentence, no matter what? Is there a situation in which the adjective complement cannot be used with an adjective because of a grammatical issue, not context?

Comment: They sound absolutely fine to a native speaker. You are probably trying to transfer some aspect of your native language to English.

Comment: Sentences b and c too?

Comment: To me, it seems those complements should not be added...

Comment: All of them are fine. Does your native language have adjective complements, and are they allowable with the verbs corresponding to *called* and *thought*?

Comment: It is hard to tell... it depends on the sentence.

Comment: Also, is there any instance that adjective complement cannot be used with adjective?

Comment: I can't think of one offhand, but that doesn't really mean much.

Comment: So the complements are always able to be attached to whatever it belongs to without any exception? (though it's optional)

Comment: Sentence C pretty much _requires_ the complement. “I called him incapable” sounds very odd, since you're always, by definition, incapable _of something_; if there is no complement, the implication is that you're incapable _of everything_, which is really only the case if you're dead (and arguably not even then).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet It depends on the context. If you were talking about an argument at work or with someone who had provided you with very poor service the nature of the incapability would be implicit.

Comment: << b. She called me different from others >> is unnatural-sounding.  << b'. She said that I was different from others >> or << b''. She deemed/judged me different from others >> sound more natural. But note that << bØ. She called me to be different from others >> has a totally different meaning.

Comment: **incapable** doesn't require a complement when its meaning is **incompetent**.   *We don't want her in our department. She's lazy, and totally incapable."  But if it's referring to a specific incapacity, it does. "She's incapable of going any faster, with her sprained ankle."

Answer (score 1):

In my dialect/idiolect (a) sounds archaic, if not obsolete; something one might find in a Dickens novel. (b) doesn't sound "native"; 'thought' or 'considered', however, is fine. (c) might pass for a native's utterance, but 'thought' sounds better & perfectly normal. To me the issue here is one of style, not grammar.

Comment: "In [your] dialect/idiolect" ... which is what?

Comment: As a native British English speaker it sounds a little archaic to me too!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any prohibition on extending object complements after "to think" and "to call". Sentence (a) does sound a bit strange to me, but I believe that "to think" is used with adjectival object complements more often in Britain (and perhaps other places) than in the U.S. I'll therefore defer to people who are more familiar with such expressions. As for (b) and (c), I think that they sound more natural in context, e.g.:

> My coach said that all members of our basketball team were quite average players. However, she called me different from the others, perhaps because I have three arms.

(Note that I inserted a definite article before "others".)

> We got into a big argument. He said that I didn't know how to cook a decent meal, and I called him incapable of doing anything properly.

I hope that both of these sentences sound alright to you; I am a native AmE speaker, and they sound fine to me.

Answer (score -1):

> And as we all know, an adjective complement can be added afterward**s**.

No. *to work with; to do the job; to work with me; of doing anything* are all adverbial.

> b. She called me different from others.
>
> c. I called him incapable of doing anything.

You may have parsed this wrongly:

A: "You are different from the others"

B: [Later] She called me [different from others.] - reported speech, It is also possible that "different" is merely a misplaced adjective, and poor grammar, used to indicate what sort of person B is.

> *c. I called him incapable of doing anything.*

In both cases, there is every possibility that "to call" = to say to someone; to tell someone - usually in a negative way: "I called him a fool."